# Rewrite url on Spring Zuul server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have a Zuul server that's redirecting an uri to an external site using proxy server configuration.

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8765
spring.main.show-banner=false

zuul.routes.resource.path=/api/**
zuul.routes.resource.url=http://www.api.com:8080
```

**Java Code**

```
@Configuration
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulServerConfig {

}
```

Is there any way to hide the real url address? I mean "/api" uri would not show for user the real url address, as we do in Apache.
This way **/api** would be only visible.

Comment: what is wrong with this arrangement. and this will not show the real url? Is it not proxying the www.api.com:8080?

Comment: Yes,  it's redirecing but i would like to rewrite the url.